Hexagon with parallel congruent sides has triangle formed by diagonals of half area
I've got this elementary geometry problem: given a hexagon ABCDEF such that AB||DE and AB=DE, BC||EF and BC=EF, CD||AF and CD=EF (a hexallelogram?), one needs to show that the area of the triangle BDF is half of the area of the hexagon.
It's easy to see that the big diagonals halve each other and are concurrent so using complex numbers and the formula from here I can just about manage a proof.
However, I would like to see an (even more) elementary solution from the geomtry wizards out there pls :)

Please show your work, instead of merely claiming that it can be done.

There is an even more elementary solution based on your observation about the big diagonals. Let them intersect at $O$. Hint:  Show that $ [OBD] = [OAB] = [ODE]$.

Let $G$ be a point in $\triangle BDF$ such that $FG = AB$ and $FG \parallel AB$ then $FG \parallel AB \parallel DE$.
$ABGF$, $BCDG$ and $DEFG$ are parallelograms.
$BD$, $DF$ and $FD$ are the diagonals of these parallelograms.
Since the diagonal of a parallelogram  divides the area into two equal parts,
Area of $\triangle BDF = \frac
{1}{2}$ Area of Hexagon $ABCDEF$


Why are you 15 minutes faster than me? :-)

@Dominique : Just sorry!
